# Using Precompiled Header for the part of source files (CMake)

Tags: cmake, precompiled-headers

```
file(GLOB SRC *.cpp)
file(GLOB SRC2 ../xx/*.cpp)

target_precompile_headers(myapp PRIVATE "$<ONLY_FOR_SRC>:stdafx.h>")
```

I tried several [CMake Generative Expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) on `ONLY_FOR_SRC` above, however, they do not work. I mean to make the files in `SRC` compiled with [precompiled header](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_precompile_headers.html), while the files in `SRC2` being compiled without precompiled header.

What is supposed to be put on where `ONLY_FOR_SRC` is above?

Answer (score 0):

One of the proper ways would be to use object libraries to separate compilation requirements:

```
file(GLOB SRC *.cpp)
file(GLOB SRC2 ../xx/*.cpp)

add_library(myapp-src OBJECT "${SRC}")
add_library(myapp-src2 OBJECT "${SRC2}")

target_precompile_headers(myapp-src PRIVATE stdafx.h)

target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE myapp-src myapp-src2)
```

You can set different include dirs, linked libraries then link all object files together.